# Creating database using mysql and querying information_schema leads to empty result

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb

In a test case for a database utility I do the following

1. Create and populate a test database using the mysql client tool
2. Query information_schema.tables

In the second step, I get an empty result.

I already tried to use FLUSH TABLES during the import as well as ANALYSE tables before querying information_schema.

I am running it with random database names.

What is going on here?

When I execute the same query -
`SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = database();` using the command line, I get the correct result.

While I believe the above information is enough to reproduce the issue, for reference, the full code is on github:

https://github.com/iMi-digital/database-helper/commit/9562a25167d154e2ac758c071de8f4a281ae7073

The failing test is \IMI\DatabaseHelper\MysqlTest::getTables .

Comment: Please explain your down / close vote

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

When constructing the MCVE I found the solution:

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, 'root', 'root');

$sth = $dbh->query("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS stackoverflow");
$sth = $dbh->query("CREATE DATABASE stackoverflow");

exec('echo "CREATE TABLE foo ( bar INT); FLUSH TABLES; " | mysql -uroot -proot -h 127.0.0.1 stackoverflow');

$sth = $dbh->query("USE stackoverflow"); // that was missing

$result = $dbh->query('SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = database();');
```